# Is raspberry Pi Stable enough

Tags: linux, web-server, server

I want to implement a SMS server which will be receiving the SMS messages sent from my devices all around the country. May be about 5 SMS per minute. I want to know if the RBP would be stable enough to do this job reliably if configured properly.

Comment: Yes RPi is stable if you do it right. Be aware though there are environmental constraints. RPi need to be mounted indoors.

Comment: yes indeed the application runs inside a Air conditioned room. so no problem about that. But could you please elaborate, "how" to configure it right to make it stable?

Comment: RPi is stable if you keep it stable. This means what you run on it may decide the stability. Power supply, ambiance are always two decisive factors. And you also need to see the throughput capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I guess it's an embedded device you want(?). That is, the opposite of a desktop computer (headless, no screen nor keyboard). You may need to reduce the number of writes to the SD-card (since it has limited lifetime). Best way for that is with an operating system which mounts the filesystem read-only. Then you can be sure of that your application is the only one writing to the SD-card. It's also a good method for keeping the system in a pristine state. A simple reboot will revert everything to the original settings.